# How to access crawled content from nutch for content categorisation

Tags: java, hdfs, nutch, tagging

I am running nutch integrated with Solr for a search engine, the nutch crawl job happens on hadoop. My next requirement is to run a content categorisation job for this crawled content, how can I access the text content that is stored in HDFS for this tagging job, I am planning to run the tagging job with Java, how can I access this content through Java ?

Answer (score 0):

The crawled content is stored in the data file in the segments directory for example:

> segments\2014...\content\part-00000\data

The file type is a sequence file. To read it you can use code from [the hadoop book](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-4/reading-a-sequencefile) or from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070587/reading-and-writing-sequencefile-using-hadoop-2-0-apis)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Solr for categorization?

Just write your own plugin and categorize pages before sending them to Solr and store category value in Solr!