# Read sequencefile in Hadoop 2.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, sequencefile

I am trying to read a sequencefile in hadoop 2.0 but I am unable to achieve it. I am using the below code which works perfectly fine in hadoop 1.0. Please let me know if I am missing something wrt 2.0

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
try {
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path p = new Path("/Users/xxx/git/xxx/src/test/cntr-20140527104344-r-00172");
SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs,p,conf);
Writable key = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getKeyClass(), conf);
Writable value = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getValueClass(), conf);
```

I am getting the below error while trying to debug.

```
2014-05-28 23:30:31,567 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(52)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2014-05-28 23:30:31,572 INFO  compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getDecompressor(121)) - Got brand-new decompressor
java.io.EOFException
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:264)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:254)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:163)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:78)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec$GzipInputStream$ResetableGZIPInputStream.<init>(GzipCodec.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec$GzipInputStream.<init>(GzipCodec.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec.createInputStream(GzipCodec.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec.createInputStream(GzipCodec.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1412)
    at com.xxx.bis.social.feedbehavior.cdl.Debuger.testSpliter(Debuger.java:30)
```

Kindly help.

Note : [Reading and Writing Sequencefile using Hadoop 2.0 Apis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070587/reading-and-writing-sequencefile-using-hadoop-2-0-apis)
I referred this link. But it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have the wrong Hadoop classes on you system.
Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos).

Comment: No I guess it has something to do with the decompression. The data is gzip compressed sequence file.