# How to know which Kind of Sequence file it is?

Tags: java, hadoop, sequencefile

I am new to Hadoop and came across few Sequence files. As I read [Sequence File](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile) there are 3 ways to create a sequence file. Now I have a sequence file , how do I know which what kind of sequence file it is. How do i read Meta information about that. I need this because, I have got a sequence file and it is expected I create a similar sequence file.

Is there any hadoop command I can use to check this information?

Answer (score 0):

> SequenceFile is a flat file consisting of binary key/value pairs. 
>   The `SequenceFile.Reader` acts as a bridge and can read any of the
>   SequenceFile formats.

**You don't need to mention the SequenceFile format to the `SequenceFile.Reader`**, by default the reader instance will get these details and decompresses the file according to the codec found in the file format.

Check out examples here:

- [Reading and Writing Sequencefile using Hadoop 2.0 Apis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072205/2142994)
- [Reading and Writing SequenceFile Example](http://hadooptutorial.info/reading-and-writing-sequencefile-example/)